# How to set clang-format options in local vimrc (.lvimrc) file?

Tags: vim

I am using [Local vimrc](https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc) for project specific vim settings. I have the .lvimrc file in my project directory with specific settings as shown below and it works.

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
```

But, I am unable to override the clang-format settings, for e.g when I run :ClangFormat, vim still uses the settings present in .vimrc file in my home folder

I have the following clang-format setting inside the .lvimrc file.

```
let g:clang_format#style_options = {
        \ "Language":                               "Cpp",
        \ "IndentWidth":                            2,
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Local vimrcs should define local options with `setlocal`, and `let b:option_name = value`.

Unfortunately not all plugins understand that some users can work on several projects simultaneously. In that case, you need your local vimrc plugin to always load local vimrc files every time you enter a buffer (even if it was already opened). And then you can protect the buffer local definitions to be (re)set again.

I can not speak for the plugin you're using. [Mine](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) reloads `vimrc_local.vim` files everytime we `BufEnter` a buffer. As a consequence the local vimrc file looks like

```
" -- Global Overridden zone for project unaware plugins
let g:some_global_option_overwritten_every_time = "forced value"

" -- Buffer local zone for project-aware plugins
if exists('b:project_foo_bar_lvimrc_loaded') && b:project_foo_bar_lvimrc_loaded != 0
    finish
endif
let b:project_foo_bar_lvimrc_loaded = 1

setlocal whatever=value
let b:some_option_for_a_smart_plugin = "specific value"

" -- and we can also add a global zone for stuff that we can load once 
" like functions, but it'll be smarter to use autoload plugins
```

BTW, reading the plugin documentation, it looks like it also listen `BufEnter`, and unlike my plugin it seems to automatically set guards. One other possibility is that your project is in a blacklisted directory tree. You'll have to check that also.

Comment: Appreciate your help Luc. I had a .clang-format hidden in my home folder which was overriding .vimrc or .lvimrc settings. Once I removed it, the .lvimrc clang-format settings worked for me.